# Silverlight datafields content alignment

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight

I simple form which have some fields. So i decided to add few DataField with textboxes and labels. Labels manageable and their length can be changed and i need to place my textboxes on the same distance from left side. How can i do this thing?

[image]

Comment: Simply, you can group the labels with a StackPanel (With default vertical orientation). The stackpanel will grows to fit the content. 

HTH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting

```
tk:DataField.IsFieldGroup="True"
```

where tk is the namespace of the toolkit for the DataField; on the parent container of all the field labels you want to be the same width.

like

```
<Grid tk:DataField.IsFieldGroup="True">...
```

That will make the labels the same width as the longest label in the FieldGroup.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a grid

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Label Content="Label" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
    <Label Content="Long Label" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"/>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>
```

Comment: Datafields have additional functionality which is very useful for me. So i need solution with them

Comment: Aah I didnt see that! HiTech Magic's answer sounds like the right way to go then.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to add control with next logic:

```
  void MyControl_LayoutUpdated(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
            if (this.columnSeparator.ActualWidth!=0&&this.columnSeparator.ActualWidth != this.columnSeparator.MinWidth)
            {
                this.IsLoaded = true;
                SetWidth();
            }
  }

 private void SetWidth()
        {
            if (IsWidthSet)
                return;
            if (!this.IsLoaded)
                return;
            var parentPanel = this.Parent as Panel;
            if (parentPanel != null)
            {
                var textFields = parentPanel.Children.Where(p => p is BpTextField).Cast<BpTextField>().ToList();
                double max = this.LabelWidth;
                foreach (var textField in textFields)
                {
                    max = Math.Max(max, textField.LabelWidth);
                    if (!textField.IsLoaded)
                        return;
                }

                foreach (var textField in textFields)
                {
                    textField.LabelWidth = max;
                }

                this.LabelWidth = max;
            }
        }
        public bool IsLoaded { get; set; }
        public bool IsWidthSet { get; set; }
```

Now all labels aligned and well.